# Can not export database by command line window

Tags: database, command-line

I exported database by command line.

**I got this error:**

> gzip is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

How to fix it ?

Comment: set the environmental variable for PATH for gzip and access

Comment: otherwise please let me know where gzip is installed?

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471210/cant-gzip-my-mysqldump-on-the-command-line-windows?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps,

1. Download gzip.exe from [http://www.gzip.org/](http://www.gzip.org/#exe)
2. Place gzip.exe in your PHP folder